# mobile charger using sound energy

Tags: sensor

My major problem is how to minimise energy input compared to output. The mic that I need to use and the op amp or transistor must powered with at least 9v. I am really stocked. Please I need your help

Comment: No, your major problem is getting enough input energy to make this idea feasible.

Comment: Unless you intend to harvest the acoustic energy very close to the exhaust of a jet-engine at full power (take-off) I do not expect this to be feasible in any way. Like Ignacio states, the amount of energy you can harvest is too little by a very long stretch.

Comment: If you get a large diameter loudspeaker (> 300 mm) and pump air in and out of the cone at high frequency (> 50 Hz) you might get a few volts off the terminals. It will weigh about 5 to 10 kg.

Answer (score 3):

Since you mention needing 9V for the microphone, it seems like you are using an electret microphone.

This is a bad choice, since as you see it needs a voltage source to even begin working.  It has a built in amplifier that requires voltage and current to operate.  This is a problem when you are trying to generate power.

A better choice would be a dynamic microphone.  These don't need an external voltage source to operate.

Even a dynamic microphone won't help much, though.

A typical dynamic microphone can only generate a few milliVolts (thousandths of a Volt.)  They are typically connected to circuits that present a load of 600 Ohms to the output of the microphone.

Lets be generous and have the microphone produce 10mVolts into a load of 600 Ohms.  That is a power output of 2 microWatts.

Your phone typically charges from a charger that puts out around 5Watts.

If your phone takes 2 hours to charge from its charger, then the energy harvested from a microphone would charge it in 1000000 hours - that'd be about 114 years if you could do it without losing any of the energy.

---

You are limited by physics.

There's only so much energy that a small volume of air can carry, and there's only so much of it you can gather with a microphone.

There are losses when converting the mechanical energy to electrical energy, and more losses when converting a low voltage signal to a higher voltag to be used.

You even lose energy in the wires.

A larger volume of air against a larger microphone membrane helps, but not enough.

Once you start getting a membrane large enough to make really measureable amounts of power, you've made the membrane so large and the coils and magnets so large that you might as well use the material to build a small wind turbine with a generator.